# ¿Cómo filtro campos de un CSV que empiezan por un carácter determinado y terminan por otro determinado?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Estoy intentando encontrar los nombres que empiezan por G y acaban con n usando `grep`, teniendo en cuenta que hay nombres compuestos. Por ejemplo: "Garhi Yasin".

Tengo las siguientes lineas de un archivo .csv:

```
Gari Yasin,10846,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Attenea,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Galim (b),10849,Valid,EH3/4-an,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
```

He probado lo siguiente:

```
grep -E "^G.*n,\b"
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve:

```
Gari Yasin,10846,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Galim (b),10849,Valid,EH3/4-an,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
```

No entiendo por qué me busca palabras más allá de la primera `,` si `\b` actúa como final de palabra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que limitar `.*` para que no contenga la coma: diciendo `[^,]*` lo consigues, pues encaja con cualquier carácter menos la coma. De este modo evitas que una "n" al final de otro campo te genere un falso positivo, como sería "**G**enial,esto,blabla**n**,".

Te quedaría pues en:

```
grep -E "^G[^,]*n,\b" fichero
```

De todos modos, a mí me gusta más gestionar este tipo de casos con Awk:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^G/ && $1 ~ /n$/' fichero
```

O incluso `$1 ~ /^G.*n$/`. Si te fijas, `$1` se refiere al primer campo (que defino por `F,` como separador por comas). Al usar `^G` y `n$` en el ámbito de este campo, no hace falta fijarnos en las comas internas. Lo bueno es que también nos valdría para mirar en todos los campos, sin tener en cuenta que en un CSV el último campo no va seguido de coma.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes el siguiente fichero:

```
$ -> cat test.txt 
Gari Yasin,10846,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Attenea,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Galim (b),10849,Valid,EH3/4-an,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
```

- Podrías extraer ya directamente la primera columna, ya que necesitas solo esa por lo que veo:

```
$ -> awk -F',' '{print $1}' test.txt 
Gari Yasin
Attenea
Galim (b)
```

Y luego aplicar la regex:

```
# Imprimes la primera columna usando como delimitador la coma, luego filtras:
$ -> awk -F',' '{print $1}' test.txt | grep -E "^G.*n$"
Gari Yasin
```

La regex `^G.*n$`:

- ^G : Obligas que comience por 'G'.
- n$ : Obligas que termine por 'n'.

Comment: Gracias Adrian, ya habia pensado en eso pero el problema es que el ejercicio en cuestión me obliga a trabajar con todo el fichero sin filtrar columnas ni usar awk. Solo el comando grep. Aun asi, muchisimas gracias, de todo se aprende!

Comment: Si estás usando Awk, salir de él para hacer un Grep suele ser innecesario: Awk provee prácticamente todo lo que querrías hacer con Grep, así como muchas otras cosas.